# C: Assigning string variable using precision specifiers like printf

Tags: c, string, variables

I want to assign a string variable using precision specifiers like printf uses and without using a ton of for loops. The code is passed in a date from the command line in the form of YYYYMMDD. To print the date in MM/DD/YYYY format, I would do the following:

```
char *date = argv[2];
printf("%.2s/%.2s/%.4s", &date[4], &date[6], date);
```

so passing '20130725' from command line will print '07/25/2013'

However, this does not work if I try:

```
char *formatted_date = ("%.2s/%.2s/%.4s", &date[4], &date[6], date);
printf("%s\n", formatted_date);
```

Passing '20130725' from command line will print '20130725' back.

How would I assign a variable in a way similar to this, or is this not possible in C?

Comment: `char *formatted_date = ("%.2s/%.2s/%.4s", &date[4], &date[6], date);`  seems you came from Python .. not its not valid code in C

Comment: Wow you hit the nail on the head with that one xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it at initialization time, but you can use `sprintf(3)`:

```
char formatted_date[11]; // MM/DD/YYYY plus a null terminator
sprintf(formatted_date, "%.2s/%.2s/%.4s", &date[4], &date[6], date);
printf("%s\n", formatted_date);
```

Comment: Carl: Better to suggest snprintf, OP came from Python knowledge where segfault doesn't happen.

Comment: Widths are explicit in the format string, so that's hardly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

That does not work in C.  You can use `sprintf`, see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)