# Assign String w/ formatter

Tags: java, printf

I want to assign a string a value using the printf.

I want to do something like this:

```
String b = printf("Base Price:          $%,.2f\n", basePrice);
```

Is this possible?

(very similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866085/c-assigning-string-variable-using-precision-specifiers-like-printf), but it's in C).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`String::format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

```
String b = String.format("Base Price:          $%,.2f\n", basePrice);
```